# JSON.net serialize directly from oledbconnection

Tags: c#, json, json.net, oledbconnection

I currently have a handler which takes the filepath and tabname for an excel file, processes the file into a datatable and then serializes the table into a json string to return.
This is working until I try to process large file, and then I get an out of memory exception.

I was thinking that it would reduce the memory usage if I didn't load everything into the datatable first, and instead loaded straight into the json string. However, I have been unable to find any examples of how to do this.

Can I serialize directly from the OleDbConnection into a string? How?

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string path = context.Request["path"];
        string tableNames = context.Request["tableNames"];

        string connectionString = string.Empty;
        if (path.EndsWith(".xls"))
        {
            connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                Data Source={0};
                Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1""", path);
        }
        else if (path.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
        {
            connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                Data Source={0};
                Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1""", path);
        }
        DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");

        DbDataAdapter adapter = factory.CreateDataAdapter();
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();

        DataTable tmp = new DataTable();

        DbCommand selectCommand = factory.CreateCommand();

        selectCommand.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", tableNames);
        selectCommand.Connection = conn;
        adapter.SelectCommand = selectCommand;


        adapter.Fill(tmp);
        string tabdata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tmp);
        context.Response.Write(tabdata);
    }
```

Comment: Where do run out of memory?  Filling the `DataTable`?  Or creating the `string`?  You're most likely to run out of memory first creating the string because a large string requires a large contiguous array of 2-byte chars.

Comment: Yes, it runs out of memory when trying to fill the string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, you should stop serializing to an intermediate `string` and instead serialize directly to the [`HttpResponse.OutputStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.outputstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), using the following simple methods:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static void SerializeToStream(object value, System.Web.HttpResponse response, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        if (response == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("response");
        SerializeToStream(value, response.OutputStream, settings);
    }

    public static void SerializeToStream(object value, TextWriter writer, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        if (writer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("writer");
        var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }

    public static void SerializeToStream(object value, Stream stream, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        if (stream == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            SerializeToStream(value, writer, settings);
        }
    }
}
```

Since a large string requires a large *contiguous* block of memory for the underlying `char` array, that's where you are going to run out of memory first.  See also Json.NET's [Performance Tips](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm)

> To minimize memory usage and the number of objects allocated, Json.NET supports serializing and deserializing directly to a stream. Reading or writing JSON a piece at a time, instead of having the entire JSON string loaded into memory, is especially important when working with JSON documents greater than 85kb in size to avoid the JSON string ending up in the large object heap.

Next, be sure to wrap all your disposables in a `using` statement, as is shown below.

That might solve your problem, but if it doesn't, you can serialize an [`IDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to JSON using the following [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm):

```
public class DataReaderConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(IDataReader).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return false; } }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var reader = (IDataReader)value;
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                writer.WritePropertyName(reader.GetName(i));
                if (reader.IsDBNull(i))
                    writer.WriteNull();
                else
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, reader[i]);
            }
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}
```

And then serialize to stream as follows:

```
public static class ExcelExtensions
{
    private static string GetExcelConnectionString(string path)
    {
        string connectionString = string.Empty;
        if (path.EndsWith(".xls"))
        {
            connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
            Data Source={0};
            Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1""", path);
        }
        else if (path.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
        {
            connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
            Data Source={0};
            Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1""", path);
        }
        return connectionString;
    }

    public static string SerializeJsonToString(string path, string workSheetName, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            SerializeJsonToStream(path, workSheetName, writer, settings);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static void SerializeJsonToStream(string path, string workSheetName, Stream stream, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            SerializeJsonToStream(path, workSheetName, writer, settings);
    }

    public static void SerializeJsonToStream(string path, string workSheetName, TextWriter writer, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        settings = settings ?? new JsonSerializerSettings();
        var converter = new DataReaderConverter();
        settings.Converters.Add(converter);
        try
        {
            string connectionString = GetExcelConnectionString(path);
            DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (DbCommand selectCommand = factory.CreateCommand())
                {
                    selectCommand.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", workSheetName);
                    selectCommand.Connection = conn;

                    using (var reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        JsonExtensions.SerializeToStream(reader, writer, settings);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            settings.Converters.Remove(converter);
        }
    }
}
```

Note - lightly tested.  Be sure to unit-test this against your existing method before putting it into production!  For the converter code I used [JSON Serialization of a DataReader](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Apr/24/JSON-Serialization-of-a-DataReader) as an inspiration.

**Update**

My converter emits JSON in the same structure as the [`DataTableConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/DataTableConverter.cs) of Json.NET.  Thus you're going to be able to deserialize to a `DataTable` automatically using Json.NET.  If you prefer a more compact format, you could define your own, for instance:

```
{
  "columns": [
    "Name 1",
    "Name 2"
  ],
  "rows": [
    [
      "value 11",
      "value 12"
    ],
    [
      "value 21",
      "value 22"
    ]
  ]
}
```

And them create the following converter:

```
public class DataReaderArrayConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(IDataReader).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return false; } }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    static string[] GetFieldNames(IDataReader reader)
    {
        var fieldNames = new string[reader.FieldCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            fieldNames[i] = reader.GetName(i);
        return fieldNames;
    }

    static void ValidateFieldNames(IDataReader reader, string[] fieldNames)
    {
        if (reader.FieldCount != fieldNames.Length)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unequal record lengths");
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            if (fieldNames[i] != reader.GetName(i))
                throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Field names at index {0} differ: \"{1}\" vs \"{2}\"", i, fieldNames[i], reader.GetName(i)));
    }

    const string columnsName = "columns";
    const string rowsName = "rows";

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var reader = (IDataReader)value;
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        string[] fieldNames = null;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (fieldNames == null)
            {
                writer.WritePropertyName(columnsName);
                fieldNames = GetFieldNames(reader);
                serializer.Serialize(writer, fieldNames);
                writer.WritePropertyName(rowsName);
                writer.WriteStartArray();
            }
            else
            {
                ValidateFieldNames(reader, fieldNames);
            }

            writer.WriteStartArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                if (reader.IsDBNull(i))
                    writer.WriteNull();
                else
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, reader[i]);
            }
            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }
        if (fieldNames != null)
        {
            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

Of course, you'll need to create your own deserialization converter on the client side.

Alternatively, you could consider compressing your response.  I've never tried it, but see [HttpWebRequest and GZip Http Responses](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2007/Jun/29/HttpWebRequest-and-GZip-Http-Responses) and [ASP.NET GZip Encoding Caveats](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/02/ASPNET-GZip-Encoding-Caveats).

Comment: Thanks, I think that did it for me!

Comment: It's the WriteJson method that is actually building the string, correct? The structure I get back has the column headers with every data row: `[{"ColA":"20012511","ColB":"ABC","ColC":"EA","ColD":null},
{"ColA":"20013092","ColB":"DEF","ColC":"EA","ColD":"1"},
{"ColA":"20013092","ColB":"GHI","ColC":"EA","ColD":"d"}]`
Is it possible to modify that method to return the headers just once first (maybe something something like this):
`[{"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD"}],
[{"20012511","ABC","EA",:null},
{"20013092","DEF","EA","1"},
{"20013092","GHI","EA","d"}]`

Comment: @wham12 - 1) your alternate JSON is invalid according to http://jsonlint.com/.  I'd need to see a valid example to comment.  2) My converter is intended to emit the same JSON as JSON.NET's [built-in data table converter](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/DataTableConverter.cs).  Are you seeing an inconsistency between my converter's behavior and the default behavior?

Comment: Yeah, from what I'm reading, it sounds like I was just asking for something JSON doesn't intend for you to do. I was thinking that we could remove the names from every record and cut the size of the data being return in half (since I know what my column names are going to be).

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for!! This is being returned to a Handsontable which I was easily able to point to the rows and columns arrays. I ran some tests using both your new WriteJson and IIS7's built in GZip. The original response was 54.9MB and took 50.36 seconds - after GZip was 1.7MB and took 49.44 seconds. The new format with the column names only once was 19.4MB and took 45.76 seconds - after GZip was 1.1MB and took 51.49 seconds.

Comment: @dbc this is the only complete example I could find on the internet on implementing json converters and using streams. Great answer