# Possible Design Pattern for Business Scenario involving large result set from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, rest, pushstreamcontent

**Scenario**: I have been given a task that involves creating a web API which will take a date parameter in the url like below:

```
https://server/controllerrouting/payments?requestdate=08/13/2016
```

This api will call a stored procedure which uses the date from the url in the select statement. The api will then return the result set as a json response to the calling application which *will not* be a front end facing application.

**Problem:** this would normally be no problem to return the result set returned from the stored procedure execution. However, the result set is expected to possibly return up to 350,000 records at around 350 bytes for each record.

**Possible Design Solution?**

I am looking into utilizing the `PushStreamContent` class and pushing the data to a stream for the client to consume.

**Question**

After executing the stored procedure and reading the result set using `DataReader`, can I push each record to the stream at this point in the logic?

Something like :

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
     while (reader.Read())
     {
         1.format record 
         2.serialize to json
         3.push record to stream
    }
}
else
{
   return msg("No rows found");
}

reader.Close();
```

What is the correct way to do this? Is it possible to just return the large json object the client and not worry about having to stream the data ? Do I need to consider paging with the stored procedure or just retrieve all of the records at once then stream only a chunk at a time to the client ? I'm having a hard time understanding what the best method is to attack this situation.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?  http://weblogs.asp.net/andresv/asynchronous-streaming-in-asp-net-webapi

Comment: 1) You can stream directly from an `IDataReader` to a JSON stream using [tag:json.net].  See [JSON.net serialize directly from oledbconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33835729).  As for streaming from web API, see [WebAPI StreamContent vs PushStreamContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168683).

Comment: thank you both for the responses. both of those articles touch on what I'm looking for. I'm going to give it a try. thanks again.