# An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code, while creating json file

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

Got an error while getting data from database in json format and create json file on web server using asp.net c#.  I have to create json file of around 400 000 records of SQL Server.

Error shows in line:

```
string jsondata = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(stockdet);
```

There is around 400 000 records in database table

> An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: 1) What is the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception, if any?  2) Can you [edit] your question to clarify *4 lacs records*?  Perhaps this is a typo?  3) Is there any way to expand your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: I have to create json file of around 400000 records of SQL Server

Comment: Maybe [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) can handle 400000  records?

Comment: Likely you're hitting the .Net [max string length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/140468).  What you want to do is to serialize directly to a stream, but `JavaScriptSerializer` does not support this.  Instead, switch to [tag:json.net] and then use `DataReaderConverter` from [JSON.net serialize directly from oledbconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33837306/3744182) to stream directly from your `IDataReader` to the file without ever loading the entire query result into memory.

Comment: I don't know how to handle it in Json.Net

Comment: actually after this  => string jsondata = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(stockdet);
        I am creating file like this = > System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "stock.json", jsondata);

Comment: @Shail - the linked answer to [JSON.net serialize directly from oledbconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33837306/3744182) shows how to serialize directly to a stream.  See also the documentation page [Serialize JSON to a file](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeWithJsonSerializerToFile.htm).

Comment: @Shail - *actually after this .. I am creating file like this...* - and this is why you are running out of memory.  You need to skip the in-memory string representation of your JSON and serialize directly to a file.  Anyway, to give a proper answer I think we need to know what `stockdet` is -- i.e. a [mcve].

Comment: please show where the exception occurred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that your memory is not enough to handle this huge object as you are trying to serialize 400 000 records, so I would suggest to follow this approach

1. Go to nuget packages and add the newtonsoft.json
2. Add the following references

   ```
   using Newtonsoft.Json;
   using System.IO;
   ```
3. place the following code

   ```
   //replace {path} with your path
   using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"{path}\temp.json"))
           using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
           {
               new JsonSerializer().Serialize(writer, stockdet);

           }
   ```
4. read the serialized object from the file located at the {path}

Comment: Thanks James, Solved my problem.