# Write all results from a DataReader, as JSON, to a file while keep entire result set out of memory

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, ado.net, advantage-database-server

I need to export data from an Advantage DB, in C# .NET Standard, and write the results in JSON format to file. However, since the amount of data that gets returned can be large, I need to avoid pulling in the entire result set into memory at any given time.

This is my current solution, which ignores the memory constraint.

```
AdsConnection conn = new AdsConnection(payload.connectionString);
AdsCommand command;
AdsDataReader reader;

try {
  conn.Open();

  command = conn.CreateCommand();
  command.CommandText = (string) payload.query;
  reader = command.ExecuteReader();

  var data = new DataTable();
  data.Load(reader);

  return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.None, new TrimmingConverter());
} catch (Exception e) {
  return e;
} finally {
  if (conn != null) {
      conn.Close();
  }
}
```

Loading the reader into a `DataTable` was the best solution I could find to easily create a representation of the data that could be serialized by Newtonsoft, but `data.Load(reader)` this is almost certainly pulling in the entire result set into memory.

It seems I can stream the serialization using something along the lines of the following code

```
AdsConnection conn.Open();
AdsCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = (string) payload.query;
AdsDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

DataTable data = new DataTable();
data.Load(reader);

using (FileStream fs = File.Open(@"c:\db_export.json", FileMode.CreateNew))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
using (JsonWriter jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{ 
  JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
  serializer.Serialize(jw, data);
}
```

However, I can't seem to find a way around loading the result set entirely into a `DataTable` first. Is there any way I can stream the result set of the `DataReader` directly to `JsonSerializer`?

Comment: Use the reader directly instead of loading the entire dataset into a DataTable. You'll have to write the elements out one by one, using JsonWriter's methods like `WriteStartObject`, `WriteEndObject`

Comment: As @PanagiotisKanavos said, try a loop `while(reader.Read()){/*Do your stuff*/}`

Comment: You may be able to use the JsonSerializer inside the loop to write individual objects, but you'd still have to explicitly emit the array start/end elements

Comment: Does [JSON.net serialize directly from oledbconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33835729/3744182) answer your question?  `DataReaderConverter` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33837306/3744182) works for any `IDataReader`.